# In Flink table API, how do you use postgres timestamps in scan.partition.column scan.partition.lower-bound etc

Tags: apache-flink, partition, flink-sql, flink-table-api

In Flink 1.13, how do you configure a CREATE TABLE statement to use a postgres timestamp column to partition by?

Things I have tried:

In postgres, I have a column named 'my_timestamp' of type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

In my Flink CREATE TABLE statement, I'm specifying it as the partition column like so:

```sql
...
my_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
...
'scan.partition.column' = 'my_timestamp',
'scan.partition.num' = '4',
'scan.partition.lower-bound' = '" + lower_bound_bigint + "',
'scan.partition.upper-bound' = '" + upper_bound_bigint + "'
```

Where variables `lower_bound_bigint` and `upper_bound_bigint` are epoch seconds of java type `long`.

`lower-bound` and `upper-bound` don't like `String` representations of times, whereas they seem to accept `long`s.

However, this results in malformed queries being sent to postgres, producing the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= bigint
```

I thought Flink would take care of converting the `long` timestamps to postgres `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in the generated `WHERE` clause, but apparently not.

The documentation says you can use timestamps for partitioning, but I'm not sure how to complete the pattern, nor how to intercept the longs in the query's generated `WHERE` clause to manually cast back to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, if that's what's needed.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/#partitioned-scan

Comment: Could you add some examples of time strings which you have tried?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to declare a computed (bigint) column and try to partition on that.

Comment: @bzu I since realized that only .column supports timestamp. .lower-bound and .upper-bound only support ints, so putting time strings there is not going to work, no matter how they're formatted. There must be some internal, or hookable way to convert ints to timestamps in the where clause, but none I've been able to find.

Comment: @bzu using a computed column removes the benefit of postgres indexes and partitions, resulting in full table scans for each query

Comment: I see, then it seems that the docs are incorrect about supporting timestamps. Maybe you can open an issue on Flink Jira (at least for improvement of the docs).